# If $x/y = 0$, does $x$ have to equal $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm a college student in Calculus I. This question came up on a quiz. The professor's answer implied that if $x/y = 0$, $x$ does not have to equal zero. I am curious if this is true. Thanks!

Comment: What was the professor's answer?

Comment: As an old school mathematician , I'm missing in which domain your $x$ and $y$ reside. Are they vectors, matrices, or some other fancy stuff math has in store? I'll guess you are talking about real numbers. If so, recall the rules about the real numbers being a field, and the axioms that come whit it.

Comment: Assuming that ${x \over y}$ is meaningful then $y \neq 0$ and you **must** have $x=0$.

Comment: I haven't got the professor's answer yet. And it was a limit question; however, I believed that it went down (to the essentials) in if x/y = 0, does x have to equal 0.

Answer (score 1):

For a well defined expression we need $y\neq 0$ and therefore

$$\frac x y =0 \iff y\cdot \frac x y =y\cdot 0 \iff x=0$$

Are you sure your professor answer's implies that $x\neq 0$?

In case we are dealing with limits, what is true is that

$$\lim_{y\to \infty} \frac x y =0$$

that is $\frac x y\to 0$ which is different concept with respect to $\frac x y= 0$.

Comment: When I was rely young, I would have asked about $y=\infinity$" and I guesses the OP is wondering about that, too.

Comment: @GyroGearloose In this case we should write that $\frac x y \to 0 $ which is different from $\frac x y =0 $.

Comment: yes, but a freshman would not know about those fine tunes.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Yes of course! Indeed thanks for the suggestion I've added something on that.

Comment: And even Paul Dirac, one of the founders of quantum mechanics was confused by that and had to be *guided* by von Neumann for his worst mathematical errors, not withstanding his ingenious thoughts to quantum physics.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally,

$$
\frac{x}{y}
$$

means 'what number, when multiplied by $y$, gives you $x$?'. If $x/y=0$, then this implies that

$$
y\times0=x
$$

Anything multiplied by $0$ is $0$. Hence, $x=0$.

Note that $y$ can't equal infinity because infinity is not a number. The following expression does not make sense

$$
\frac{x}{\infty}=0
$$

However, we can say that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x}{n}=0
$$

This expression means 'as $n$ gets larger and larger, $x/n$ gets smaller and smaller'. It does not mean that if $n=\infty$, then $x/n=0$.

Comment: "Note that y can't equal infinity because infinity is not a number." Ah, have a look at what  those quantum mechanics think math to be like and use Dirac function as it was an real value. And, magically, they even come out with an applicable result.

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y$ are numbers then automatically $\frac xy=0\implies x=0y=0$

Now being a bit informal it is also true that $\frac x\infty=0$ regardless the value of number $x$, but $\infty$ is not a number $y$.

Maybe what your professor meant was an informal way of looking at $x,y$ as potential limits, understand *do we need $f(t)\to 0$* if we have $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}\to 0$, not necessarily since $g(t)\to\infty$ is also a solution (assuming $f$ bounded for instance).

We often do informal calculus when talking about limits, for instance $\frac{3+x}{x^2}\to \frac 30=\infty$ or $|x\sin(x)|^{\frac 1x}\to 0^\infty=0$. But keep in mind this is still informal (these final equal signs, are abuse of notation), even if this helps figuring quickly what the final result should be.